In EXM when selected the recipient, not able to see the recipients and unable to send email campaign
In Sitecore List manager I can upload the contact list CSV file and also able to see the no. of recipient once it is uploaded. But when I am trying to create a regular email campaign in EXM, I can update all the fields there but, in recipient when I select the include list that is uploaded, in list manager, I see the included list as 0 in Email campaign info, if I select anything in excluded list same I can see i.e 0, in Email campaign info.
after that when I tried to deliver it by clicking send campaign, but I got an error while sending it.

"You must add at least one populated recipient list to the message".

Anyone can guide me to resolve the issue?
note: Also I would like to mention my Marketing Automation service is not running in my local, any idea how to fix this too?

Your ListManagement and Marketing Automation issues stem from the same ancient bugs with Language versions.
I’ll write an answer when I’m behind a computer, but you should find the Contact Lists in the Content Editor and manually create language versions and then REDEPLOY them.
You also need to do the same for every item under Marketing Automation.

Can you share the error logs from Marketing Automation instance..

doesn't have any error in log rather than this-
Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
Message: Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.

This issue happens when the context language of the user is not en. In that case the items under the markting control panel for contact list and subscription, will not contain en version.
In order to avoid this issue, you can create the en version for items as below, under marketing control panel for the list manager created.
/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Contact Lists
/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Subscriptions

Once the en version for the list manager item is created in above two paths, you can deploy these definitions from the Review tab as below.

Using above changes, you should be able to see the List Manager count getting reflected while creating Email Campaign.
Note: You can do these changes on the existing list manager items. In order to avoid this issue for the new list manager items, create the following changes as recommended in this article.
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0558878
Hope this helps. Let me know in case you face any issues.

Sitecore Support recognised this as Known Issue 328917 / KB0558878: "Included Recipient count is not updated if content language differs from English" - it's fixed in Sitecore 10.4
The article provides a workaround for those on previous versions:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0558878
I've asked Sitecore to include the "You must add at least one populated recipient list to the message" phrase on the page to make it findable by search engines.
